# How can I add items to an sqlite3 database with python with unique indicies and retain the new index while clients rapidly access the database

Tags: python, sql, python-2.7, sqlite

I am writing a genetic algorithm in python that makes use of a sqlite3 database to store information about a structure and its properties.

I have a separate table for structure and property and therefore need to know the index of the newly added structure so that it can be referenced in the property table. I would like to use the `struct_id INT IDENTITY(1,0) PRIMARY KEY,` command, but I can't seem to immediately retrieve the new id from the cursor.

This wouldn't normally be a problem as the additions happen serially, but the plan is to have dozens of individual processes writing to this database simultaneously.

My current attempt is below, but I've found that the structure ids are being overwritten when many processes rapidly write to the database.
Thanks in advance.

```
def add_structure(self, struct):
    '''
    inserts a structure and its properties into a sqlite database and returns the struct_id
    '''
    conn = self.get_conn()
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    # insert structure
    new_id = -1  # initialize
    while True:
        # select current max id number and add one
        new_id = cursor.execute('SELECT max(struct_id) FROM structure').fetchone()[0] + 1
        # attemts to insert. If structure with id already exists, error is returned and loop restarts
        try:
            cursor.execute('INSERT INTO structure (struct_id, input_id, stoic, geo) \
                            VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)',
                            (new_id, self.input_ref, self.stoichiometry.get_string(), struct.get_geometry()))

            prop_list = []
            for prop in struct.properties.iteritems():
                prop_list.append((new_id, prop[0], str(prop[1]),))
            cursor.executemany('INSERT INTO property (struct_id, key, value) \
                            VALUES (?, ?, ?)', prop_list)
            conn.commit()
        except Exception,e: print str(e); continue # structure id clash, re-evaluate new id
        break # if successful

    # insert attributes
    conn.commit()
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()

    if new_id > 0:  # no errors 
        struct.index = new_id
        print 'structure added to DB with ID: ' + str(new_id)
        return new_id
    else: raise Exception  # insertion problem
```

Comment: *but the plan is to have dozens of individual processes writing to this database simultaneously* - sqlite is already the wrong choice here then... From a cursory glance, it almost sounds like a keystore db might be better suited...

Comment: Really?... that's a bummer. Quite a bit of my architecture is built around having an embedded database. I'm looking for information on a keystore db but it look more to be designed for encrypted keys. What is it about my problem that suggests a keystore?

Comment: sqlite isn't really designed to be written to by multiple processes (it doesn't mean you can't do it, just that it's not wonderfully efficient)... by "keystore" - I should have probably say "key-value" store...

Answer (score 0):

My mistake!
I made an error in testing and the index was actually the proper one. So in short, my code works. If you're running in to the same problem, feel free to use mine as a framework. Be sure to surround any execute statement in a try-catch block, even if it's just a read, the database could be locked and throw an exception.